# PHP: need add-on for fpdf converter that support ul li tag

Tags: php, html, pdf, fpdf

I am using the fpdf for converting dynamic site content to pdf but it does not support ul li tag. Can anyone help with an fpdf add-on that supports ul li and ol li tags in html.

Just to be more detailed about the challenge:

The content being generated into pdf document isnt static rather it's dynamic and fetched from the database based user selection. The content are for various course and their detail information being generated and the detail for each are in html. The fpdf is working and generating each course detail in pdf but in a case where a course detail has some ul li listing in it html details, it would not be generated in ul li (i.e each li tag would not force a line break like it ought to rather all the li listing would output on a single line) because these tags are not supported.

Furthermore, about the html for each courses being generated, they are pretty okay cos user would have to view the same html on a specific page for course detail before deciding to click the "Get course detail in pdf"...So i would like to state that the html codes for these courses are okay.

Here is the code for generating the pdf document:

```
<?php

@include_once("includes/db.php");

define('FPDF_FONTPATH', 'font/');
@require('fpdf/WriteHTML.php');

@include_once("includes/class_open_courses.php");

$obj = new openCourses();
$course_details = array();
if(isset($_GET['c_id'])){
        $course_details = $obj->getOpenCourseDet($_GET['c_id']);



// Instanciation of inherited class
$pdf = new PDF_HTML();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();


$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);

// Course title cell
$pdf->Cell('',10,$course_details['title'],0,0,'C');
$pdf->Ln();

/* Build cells for the first row */

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->SetY(40);

// First Row
$pdf->Cell(35,8,'Start Date : ',0,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(30,8,$course_details['event_date'],0,0,'L');
$pdf->SetX(140);
$pdf->Cell(25,8,'Course Fee : ',0,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(20,8,$course_details['currency_sign'].$course_details['price'],0,0,'C');
$pdf->Ln();


// Fourth Row
$pdf->SetY(65);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(35,8,'Course Details',0,0,'L');
$pdf->Ln();


$pdf->SetY(65);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->WriteHTML($course_details['desc']);


//$pdf->WriteHTML('<p>line 1</p> <ul><li>list 1</li><li>list 2</li><li>list 3</li></ul>');


$pdf->Output();



}
else {

?>
    <script language="javascript">
    window.location = "course_info.php?c_id=".<?php echo $course_details['id']; ?>.";
    </script>
<?php
}




?>
```

Would be very grateful if anyone can help with this.

Comment: Can you please print your html code on browser whether it is proper or not.

Answer (score 0):

I used PDF_HTML() and added this for UL/LI-Support:

**function OpenTag**

```
        case 'UL':
            $this->Ln(2);
            break;
        case 'LI':
            $this->Ln(2);
            $this->setX($this->GetX() + 10);
            $this->Write(2, chr(127));
            break;
```

**function CloseTag**

```
      if($tag=='UL')
            $this->Ln(2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please Download add-on for fpdf which will support write HTML in PDF

You can download add-on here http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/41/

After download add-on include `WriteHTML.php` in your script as used in below example. Inside WriteHTML() function pass your HTML code

```
define('FPDF_FONTPATH', 'font/');
require('WriteHTML.php');

$pdf=new PDF_HTML();
$pdf->Open();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial');
$pdf->WriteHTML('Put your html here');
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: thanks for your help but im currently using this and it does not support ul li and ol li tags....

Comment: I've tried that and still not working and also i've updated the question detail. thanks.